# Looking for a way to reduce the number of VMs using Ansible by newest instances first

Tags: azure, ansible, jinja2

I am deploying any number of instances using ansible in Azure Cloud based on a `instancesCount` variable and iterating over the creation tasks for each resource (NIC, managed disk, VM, etc) using `with_sequence: count={{ instancesCount }}`. The instances, and their associated resources (managed disks, os disk, NICs) are created in the same name format:

```
{{ env }}-xxx-{{ vmName }}-{{ count }}:
say instancesCount is 3:
dev-xxx-myvm-1
dev-xxx-myvm-1-nic
dev-xxx-myvm--1-osDisk
dev-xxx-myvm-2
dev-xxx-myvm-2-nic
dev-xxx-myvm-2-osDisk
dev-xxx-myvm-3
dev-xxx-myvm-3-nic
dev-xxx-myvm-3-osDisk
```

I am looking for a way to scale down the number of instances when the variable `instancesCount` changes to a lower integer number, say from 3 to 1, by removing the **newest** instances first: `dev-xxx-myvm-3`, `dev-xxx-myvm-2`, and their associated resources, leaving just `dev-xxx-myvm-1`.

The logic I am thinking is first gather info from Azure using Ansible modules for each resource (`azure_rm_virtualmachine_info`, `azure_rm_networkinterface_info`, `azure_rm_manageddisk_info`, etc). Save each of that in a variable of its own, and using that, and instancesCount, remove those resources that exceed, but I am not sure how to proceed..

Using jinja2 I can easily get the vm names to be removed, but cant convert this code to Ansible:

```
{% set to_remove = existing_vms.vms | length - instancesCount | int %}

{% for item in existing_vms.vms[-to_remove:] %}
{{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Was able to convert successfully:

```
    - name: Print name of vms to be removed
      debug:
        var: item.name
      loop: "{{ existing_vms.vms[-(to_remove|int):] }}"
```

Yet, one last issue: the list is not sorted. Say we have 10 instances, the `existing_vms.vms.*.name` looks like this, as its pulled from Azure:

```
dev-xxx-myvm-1
dev-xxx-myvm-10
dev-xxx-myvm-2
dev-xxx-myvm-3
dev-xxx-myvm-4
dev-xxx-myvm-5
dev-xxx-myvm-6
dev-xxx-myvm-7
dev-xxx-myvm-8
dev-xxx-myvm-9
```

How would I be able to sort the list by the trailing number in the name, ascending, before passing it to the slice operator - `[-(to_remove)|int:]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution is to look for what VMs are already deployed using `azure_rm_virtualmachine_info`, save that in a variable and sanitize the variable, then pass it to `azure_rm_virtualmachine` while specifying `remove_on_absent`. There is no need to get managed disk, nic or any other resource info as this will remove dependent resources.

1. get the deployment info:

```
- name: "Getting deployment state"
  block:
  - name: "Getting deployment state"
    azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info:
      resource_group: myRG
    register: existing_vms
  - name: Saving all VM names in vm_names
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      vm_names: "{{ vm_names | default([]) + [item.name] }}"
    loop: "{{ existing_vms.vms }}"
  - name: Sorting the VM names in vm_names_sorted
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      vm_names_sorted: "{{ vm_names | community.general.version_sort }}"
  ignore_errors: true
```

This will sort the list properly:

FROM:

```
dev-xxx-myvm-1
dev-xxx-myvm-10
dev-xxx-myvm-2
dev-xxx-myvm-3
dev-xxx-myvm-4
dev-xxx-myvm-5
dev-xxx-myvm-6
dev-xxx-myvm-7
dev-xxx-myvm-8
dev-xxx-myvm-9
```

TO:

```
dev-xxx-myvm-1
dev-xxx-myvm-2
dev-xxx-myvm-3
dev-xxx-myvm-4
dev-xxx-myvm-5
dev-xxx-myvm-6
dev-xxx-myvm-7
dev-xxx-myvm-8
dev-xxx-myvm-9
dev-xxx-myvm-10
```

2. Calculate how many we should remove:

```
- name: "Setting scale down value if instancesCount < currrent deployment"
  ansible.builtin.set_fact: 
    to_remove: "{{ vm_names_sorted | length - instancesCount | int }}"
  when: vm_names_sorted is defined and vm_names_sorted | length | int > instancesCount | int and instancesCount | int != 0
```

3. We can then pass the new list to `azure_rm_virtualmachine` to remove to_remove number of VMs, starting with the newest (dev-xxx-myvm-10, dev-xxx-myvm-9, etc):

```
- name: "Scaling down deployment to {{ instancesCount }}"
  azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: myRG
    name: "{{ item }}"
    remove_on_absent: ['network_interfaces', 'virtual_storage', 'public_ips']
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ vm_names_sorted[-(to_remove|int):] }}"
  when: to_remove is defined
```